# Alterar Propriedade em Run Time

Tags: delphi, delphi-10, runtime

Como consigo alterar a propriedade `TRectangle.Align` em *runtime* Delphi 10.2 usando *Firemonkey* para aplicação multi plataforma?

Answer (score 1):

```
Rectangle1.Align := TAlignLayout.Client;
```